# Why Not Define Connectedness to Mean Path Connected?

Tags: general-topology, definition

All spaces I have seen which are connected are also path connected (apart from examples to show that the two are not equivalent). Is there a reason for using the weaker definition of connectedness when all applications (that I have seen at least) will involve the stronger concept of path connected spaces?

Comment: Of these two notions, "connected" is the more elementary, fundamental one: Its definition refers to nothing but abstract nonsense. In contrast, the definition of "path-connected" relies on $\mathbb R$, which makes it less useful in algebraic contexts such as Zariski topology. So it makes sense for the latter notion to have a longer name than the former. But "connected" is indeed not the best choice of a name.

Comment: the short answer is that perhaps while you have not seen non-artificial examples of connected but not path-connected spaces, there are many situations where a very important space is involved which is quite often connected, but not path-connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even in the setting where you only consider path-connected spaces, connected is still a technically simpler concept, and is often easier to prove things about connectedness than it is about path-connectedness, and conversely, it is often easier to use connectedness to prove things than it is to use path-connectedness.

(assuming, of course, that you're comfortable reasoning with open sets and such)